# Python NoneType' object is not callable error from (i think) str.split function

Tags: python, split

I am trying to get information from an html file through searching all lines begining with `td` and then splitting the strings to get only the bits of a line that I want with the following code:

```
def scraper(filename):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filename), 'html.parser')
    with open("test/"+filename.stem+".txt", "w") as outfile:
        search = soup.findAll('td')
        for tag in search:
            if re.search(r'regbutton|rgba|mibig', str(tag)):
                if re.search('regbutton', str(tag)):
                    outfile.write(str(tag.split()[2]) + '\n')
                if re.search('rgba', str(tag)):
                    outfile.write(str(tag.split()[17]) + '\n')
                if re.search('mibig', str(tag)):
                    outfile.write(str(re.findall('>(.+)<')) + '\n')
```

But this results in this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "html_scrape.py", line 31, in <module>
    scraper(filename)
  File "html_scrape.py", line 23, in scraper
    outfile.write(str(tag.split()[2]) + '\n')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
(antismash_v5) [lamma@fe1 actinobacteria]$
```

I am given to understand it is due to I assume something in the `tag.split` being none but I don't know why.

Edit:

Example of the `td` tag search output:

```
<td class="regbutton NRPS r2c1">
<a href="#r2c1">Region&amp;nbsp2.1</a>
</td>
<td><a class="external-link" href="https://mibig.secondarymetabolites.org/go/BGC0000324/1" target="_blank">coelibactin</a></td>
<td class="digits similarity-text" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 100, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 100, 0, 0.3) 100%, #ffffff00 100%)">100%</td>
```

The whole file would just be a repeat of this with differing things found pretty much.

Comment: Do some debugging: `for tag in search: print(tag)` -- I'm guessing one of them are returning a null object

Comment: Make sure you haven't assigned the name `str` to something else.

Comment: @AK47 when just having `for tag in search: outfile.write(str(tag) + '\n')` I don't get the error so I am give to think tag is not null. Am I right in thinking that? @khelwood, `str` is not assigned to something else, I am just using it as the `str` function.

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/ShinyAnotherWebportal

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger here?

Comment: @cricket_007 do you mean the link posted above by AK47, I have not and am not sure how to use it. When I put code it an run it does nothing.

Comment: No. I mean using an IDE like Pycharm and setting breakpoints or learning about `pdb` module

Comment: I use Atom as my IDE and that shows no error in the code. `pdb`is a package right?

Comment: Try splitting the error line into four lines: `outfile.write(`, `str(`, `tag.split()[2]`, `) + '\n')`. The Traceback should be more exact.

Comment: @quamrana How should I be splitting? sorry i dont understand.

Comment: Press Enter in your ide at the end of each of the sections of characters I posted in my comment. That will split that one line into four lines.

Comment: I get no errors as far as I can see

Comment: So why no errors now? What happened to`'NoneType' object is not callable`?

Answer (score 0):

Debugging 101:  Simplify your problem and give yourself more information.

Your issue is with the tag.split().  So lets ignore the file.write and everything else:

```
def scraper(filename):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filename), 'html.parser')
    search = soup.findAll('td')
    for tag in search:
        print(tag)
        print(tag.split())
        print(tag.split()[2])

    #with open("test/"+filename.stem+".txt", "w") as outfile:
    #    search = soup.findAll('td')
    #    for tag in search:
    #        if re.search(r'regbutton|rgba|mibig', str(tag)):
    #            if re.search('regbutton', str(tag)):
    #                outfile.write(str(tag.split()[2]) + '\n')
    #            if re.search('rgba', str(tag)):
    #                outfile.write(str(tag.split()[17]) + '\n')
    #            if re.search('mibig', str(tag)):
    #                outfile.write(str(re.findall('>(.+)<')) + '\n')
```

Look at your output.  Is split working the way you expect?

Bonus question:  If split is a builtin string function, why are you casting everything into strings with the `str` function?

ProTip:  Use the REPL and run these commands interactively.  Use introspection to figure out what is happening.  You can use an IDE and integrated debugger, but sometimes a well placed print statement is all you need.

Comment: If i didnt include ´str´it returns error saying it must be in a string or something to that effect. I need to get PyCharm working so I can run locally but it won't let me initialise an interpreter. Trying your suggestion of the simplified code I get the same error `print(tag.split())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

So this would indicate tag is not able to be split, and I think that has something to do with it not being a string.

Comment: So after looking at the `type(tag)` it is a `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`. I assume this is where the error comes from as str.split assumes a string. I guess the type is comming from the fact it is a html file I am searching in. So the question for me now is how do I convert whatever this type is into a character string?

Comment: You are correct.  What you want is `tag.string.split() ` where you get the string representation of the tag and then perform the split.  Assuming of course the feature you are searching for is not an html attribute.  BeautifulSoup does a lot of work for you already.  Using its built in functions you should be able to whatever piece of text you are looking for without having to go down regular expressions.

Comment: So I tried     `print(tag.string)
        print(tag.string.split())
        print(tag.string.split()[2])` 
and I get this error now: `print(tag.string.split())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'`. This I believe is becuase tag now has nothing inside it? Does this then mean `.string` is unable to convert it to type sring?

Comment: Can you add an example of one of your TD tags to your question

Comment: Added the eddit. I got the `split`statment to work using `srt(tag)` but including `[2]` returned : `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'`. This is a result of the split returning nothing I think. So that means the str conversion is either not working properly or there are no spaces. Visually there are spaces but not sure what python sees them as.

Comment: If you're not sure what python sees them as, print it as a list (`print(list(string))`), and it'll show you every character separately

Comment: The tag at issue may not contain any text. If you think it should contain text but it doesn't, I'd guess the text is actually in some other tag that's nested inside the one you're looking at.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Peter. That results in : `'<', 't', 'd', ' ', 'c', 'l', 'a', 's', 's'` for `<td class` which indicated it does see spaces right?

Comment: @AutomaticStatic Where would the nesting be happening though? All the code being used is show above. I am not to familiar with nested variables in python. I understand nested function ( I think) such as what I am using with a `for`function within my `def`function ?

Comment: @Lamma you might look at a cell in a table and think it contains text, which it does to your eye. That doesn't mean the `<td>` you're looking at is actually the tag containing the text. It might be that the `<td>` you're looking at is actually some nonsense like `<td><tr><td><p>this is <br> the text</td></tr></td>`, in which case you're probably not going to get the text by calling `your_td.string` on that first `<td>` tag and instead are going to get `None`. Look at your HTML and make sure you're drilling down all the way to the nearest tag wrapping the text of interest.

Comment: `<td>` is the closest tag most of the time, sometimes it is `a` but not always so I went with `td`. I am unsure how to get around that.